# Rerendering after model change in AJAX request in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I need some help with my code for some reason I can't get my view to rerender following a model change.

```
    var ResultLoanView = Backbone.View.extend({
      id:"result",
      initialize: function(){
        this.render();
        this.on('submissionMade',this.getData,this)
        this.model.on('change',this.render,this)
      },

      template: _.template("<% _.each(models, function(data,index) { %><div><%= index %></div> <%= data %><% }); %>"),

      getData: function(){
             var that = this;
             $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url:"http://zillow.com/webservice/mortgage/CalculateAffordability.htm?",
              data: {
                "zws-id":"APIKEY",
                annualincome: 1000000,
                monthlypayment: 2000,
                down: 800000,
                monthlydebts: 1500,
                rate: 6.504,
                schedule: "yearly",
                term: 360,
                debttoincome: 36,
                incometax: 30,
                propertytax: 20,
                hazard: 20000,
                pmi: 1000,
                output: "json"
              },
              dataType: "jsonp",
              success: function(data) {
                that.model.attributes = data.response
                console.log(that.model)
                  }
              ,
              error: function(result) {
                  alert("Error");
              }
          })
      },
      render:function(){
        console.log("rerender")
        var need = this.$el.html(this.template({models:this.model.toJSON()}))
        $('body').append(need)

      }

    })
```

So when `submissionMade` gets triggered from a parent view. This kicks off an `$.ajax` request. Finally this brings back data that I want to assign to my associated model with `ResultLoanView`. For some reason the model isn't being changed because the listener in `initialize` isn't re-rendering my html. My goal is to reassign data to my model, which would re-render based off the listener in `initialize`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to call.

```
that.model.set(data.response)
```

Instead of changing the `.attributes` directly.  The docs mention change events for `set()`.

And just a side note, look up difference between `this.listenTo()` vs `model.on()`.  Many instances are better to use listenTo to prevent memory leaks.